# If I push python code, that has information containing host and key parameters, onto github, is that exposing me to malicious attack?

Tags: python, api

I'm fairly new to utilizing APIs, so please bear with me if this is a dumb question. I am writing a code using one of the APIs for [www.imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com). I had to sign up to have access. If I push my code to github and the host and key are openly given as header parameters in my code, does this expose me in any way? Like will it leave me vulnerable for malicious attacks?

Answer (score 2):

If you store an API key on a public repository, you are publishing in the open so that anyone can see it. Here are Best practices for securely using API keys:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-securely-store-api-keys-4ff3ea19ebda/
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en

Store them in environment variables or in files outside of your application's source tree.